# changing the background image of a child div when the mouse is hovered over the parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div with a background image inside another div and what I'm trying to achieve is changing that child div's background image when someone hovers anywhere over the entire parent div.

How would I achieve this?

The HTML is like:

```
<div class="parent_div">
<div class="child_div">
</div>
</div>
```

And the background image of the child div is:

```
.child_div{
    background-image: url("image.jpg");
}
```

I tried:

```
.child_div:hover{
    background-image: url("image-new.jpg");
}
```

But that changes the background only when it's hovered over the child div and since the parent div has some extra padding that I'd like to include, it's not working :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a runnable snippet, showing you how the css [Descendant](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/d/descendant/) selector would work:

```css
.parent_div{
  height:400px;
  width:100%;
  background:red;
}

.child_div {
  height:200px;
  width:100%;
  background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/g/200/200); /*initial*/
}
.parent_div:hover .child_div{
  background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/g/200/400); /*when parent is hovered*/
}
```

```html
<div class="parent_div">
  <div class="child_div">
  </div>
</div>
```

It's using the css selector:

```
.parent_div:hover .child_div{
  background:...
}
```

which means when the parent is hovered (red area in snippet), add the styling to the class of child_div as ...

This is because it is using the [Descendant](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/d/descendant/) selector to select the class .child_div who has a hovered .parent_div element. (other css selectors can be found in the [W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html))

Answer (score 3):

It should be

```
.parent_div:hover .child_div{
    background-image: url("image-new.jpg");
}
```

Basically it means: when .parent_div is hovered, .child_div background will be the new image

Answer (score 0):

You are writing an style for child element, but you need to do it for parent:

```
.parent_div .child_div{
    background-image: url('image.jpg');
}

.parent_div:hover .child_div {
    background-image: url('image-new.jpg');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this  css:

```
.parent {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

.parent img.child {
  width: auto; /* or 100% */
  height: auto; /* or 100% */
  background-image: url('old-bkg.png');
}

.parent img.child:hover{
  background-image: url('new-bkg.png');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.parent_div{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: blue;
}

.parent_div:hover .child_div{
    background: red;
}

.child_div{
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Example jsfiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/9uu9j220/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
.child_div{
   background-image: url("image.jpg");
}
.parent_div:hover .child_div{
   background-image: url("new_hovered_image.jpg");
}
```

You can see more useful selectors [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Answer (score -1):

As you tagged your question with JQuery You can try this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.parent_div').hover(function(){
    $('.child_div').css('background-image','url(urImg.jpg)');
  });


});
```